# embed youtube link not working on chrome but working on IE

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, youtube

I have a website where I was testing my code using the ui.educateglobal.org/youtube_embebd.html Here is the most relevant code snippet.

```
<param name="movie" value="feature=player_embedded">
<embed
    src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k&hl=en_US&fs=1&rel=0&hd=1&border=0&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=youtube_player" height="445" width="800" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="opaque" name="youtube_player"
    id="youtube_player"/>
</param>
```

The video plays for me on IE but not on Chrome. I don't know why that is the case.

Comment: its playing for me in chrome? specify your version. Mine version is Version 36.0.1985.143 m

Comment: Its working perfectly in my chrome browser. May be its a bug

Comment: Google Chrome 36.0.1985.143 (Official Build 287914) m So need to reinstall now?

Comment: Yes. check the settings also of your browser, might be missing something. Because here it is working perfectly for me.

Comment: I restarted my browser and it is working now. As a side comment, in html if u use '/'(backslash) at the end of any tag <embed /> does it matter? For the above code even when I remove the '/' in  id="youtube_player"/  still the code functions correctly.

Comment: first of all for closing tag </embed> is the correct way. However it should not matter to stop the functionality of the code. Just check thorugh the syntax of opening and closing tag if you have any doubts

Comment: This link http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp showed that you did not need it for embed but needed it for object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's playing for me in chrome. Mine version is Version *36.0.1985.143 m*

Just check the settings of the browser and install *necessary plugins* related to it. It should work, as it is working fine for me.